# Java Linked List implementing an Interface. Node error

Tags: java, generics, interface

Project for school is giving me errors and I am not sure how to fix. I wrote code similar regarding Linked Lists before in a lab and it worked fine. Using intellij, 'Node' is in red and says it cannot resolve symbol. The exact code in another program worked fine. I think it has to do with the Interface it is implementing is extending Collection. 
This is the beginning of the code I have written.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class LinkedMerge<Q> implements MergeInterface<Q> {
    private Node head;
    private int length;

    public LinkedMerge(){
        clear();
    }

    public boolean add(Q q) {
        Node newNode = new Node(q);

        if (isEmpty()){
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node lastNode = getNodeAt(length);
            lastNode.next = newNode;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

MergeInterface looks a bit like this,

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface MergeInterface<Q> extends Collection<Q> {

 + many methods that I have implemented in LinkedMerge +

 }
```

Why is Node not working correctly? How would I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the Node class defined?

Comment: Where have you defined "Node"?